# jQuery - How to start a script when the scroll reaches the block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a jQuery "*homemade*" script (that I found here) and I'de like to start this one when the scroll reaches the tab block *(the blue and grey block at the end of the page)*.

Here is a [live version](http://bp-design.fr/Codeur/)

My HTML :

```
<section id="Block" class="container-fluid block">
    <div class="row accordeon">
        <div class="blue">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
              <li class="active"><a href="#deposer">1 - Déposez un projet appel d’offre et recevez en moyenne 10 devis</a></li>
              <li><a href="#comparer">2 - Comparez les devis et négociez librement</a></li>
              <li><a href="#choisir">3 - Choississez le prestataire que vous voulez, quand vous voulez</a></li>
              <li><a href="#payer">4 - Payez le prestataire par le moyen de votre choix</a></li>
              <li><a href="#evaluer">5 - Evaluez le prestataire sur Codeur.com</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="gray">
            <div class="tab-content">
              <div class="tab-pane active" id="deposer">
                <h4 class="text-left">1 - Déposez un projet appel d’offre et recevez en moyenne 10 devis</h4>
                <p>Sans même vous inscrire, vous publiez votre projet. Il correspond à un appel d'offres auquel les prestataires vont répondre. C'est gratuit et l'inscription se fait automatiquement et simultanément.</p>
                <p>Une fois le projet publié sur Codeur, les prestataires concernés sont avertis. Vous n'avez rien d'autre à faire. Vous recevez rapidement des devis gratuits qui seront classés sous la description de votre projet.</p>
                <p>En savoir plus sur le dépot de projet :</p>
                <ul class="unstyled">
                    <li><a class="shake" href="#">Comment créer mon projet ?<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="shake" href="#">Comment bien décrire mon projet ?<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="comparer">
                <h4 class="text-left">2 - Comparez les devis et négociez librement</h4>
                <p>Comparez les devis et discutez avec leurs prestataires par messagerie privée, par messagerie instantanée ou par téléphone (si vous le souhaitez). Vous pouvez aussi modifier votre projet et donner des précisions aux prestataires. Vous négociez librement et mettez les prestataires en concurrence pour obtenir les meilleurs prix et délais et les meilleures prestations.</p>
                <p>En savoir plus sur :</p>
                <ul class="unstyled">
                    <li><a class="shake" href="#">Comment inviter un prestataire à faire une offre sur mon projet ?<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="shake" href="#">Comment utiliser la messagerie ?<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="choisir">
                <h4 class="text-left">3 - Choississez le prestataire que vous voulez, quand vous voulez</h4>
                <p>C'est vous qui décidez quand et si vous sélectionnez un prestataire. Vous sélectionnez la personne que vous voulez. C'est très simple, il vous suffit de le sélectionner à partir de la fiche de votre projet.</p>
                <p>Choisir un prestataire sur Codeur vous permettra de l'évaluer à l'issue de sa prestation. Vous pouvez aussi demander, avant de commencer le projet, de signer un devis en bonne et due forme.</p>
                <ul class="unstyled">
                    <li><a class="shake" href="#">Comment choisir un prestataire pour réaliser mon projet ?<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="shake" href="#">Pourquoi attribuer un projet sur Codeur.com est il plus sûr ?<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="payer">
                <h4>4 - Payez le prestataire par le moyen de votre choix</h4>
                <p>C'est vous qui décidez comment vous réglez votre prestataire. Vous discutez avec lui du moyen de paiement qui vous convient à tous les deux. Pour plus de sécurité, vous pouvez bloquer le paiement sur <a href="#">Codeur Tasks</a> en début de projet, et vous libérez le paiement par étape : à chaque étape réalisée correspond un paiement. Cela permet d'éviter la plupart des litiges.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tab-pane" id="evaluer">
                <h4>5 - Evaluez le prestataire sur Codeur.com</h4>
                <p>Dès la fin du projet, vous pouvez évaluer le prestataire. Votre évaluation sera publiée sur le site et si elle est positive, aidera le prestataire à trouver de nouveaux projets. Le prestataire pourra également vous évaluer et ainsi renforcer votre réputation sur Codeur.com pour trouver un prestataire lors de la publication d'un prochain projet.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My script for scrolling :

```
<!-- Show anim on Scroll -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
      $(window).scroll( function(){
          /* Check the location of each desired element */
          $('.ShowMe').each( function(i){
              var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
              var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
              /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
              if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
                  $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
              }
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

My script for the tab animation :

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<script>
    var tabChange = function () {
      var tabs = $('.nav-tabs > li');
      var active = tabs.filter('.active');
      var next = active.next('li').length ? active.next('li').find('a') : tabs.filter(':first-child').find('a');
      // Use the Bootsrap tab show method
      next.tab('show');
    };
    // Tab Cycle function
    var tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);

    // Tab click event handler
    $('a').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stop the cycle
      clearInterval(tabCycle);
      // Show the clicked tabs associated tab-pane
      $(this).tab('show');
      // Start the cycle again in a predefined amount of time
      setTimeout(function () {
      //tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);
      }, 15000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does the script not start? Please explain more

Comment: The both work. The problem is that i'de like to start the second script "tab" start when the user scrolls the page and reaches the block. Do you understand ?

Comment: Do you have an idea @Rotan075 ?

Comment: Look at my answer @bep42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first off all you need to check if the object is within your screen after you scroll. If you reach the object then check with an if statement if the object is visible and then you should execute your code.

Look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uxu8o6eo/) and see the whole JS function.

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (checkVisible($('#tester'))) {
        alert("Visible!!! Paste your code in this if function!")        
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

In your case would that be:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (checkVisible($('#tester'))) {
        var tabChange = function () {
          var tabs = $('.nav-tabs > li');
          var active = tabs.filter('.active');
          var next = active.next('li').length ? active.next('li').find('a') : tabs.filter(':first-child').find('a');
          // Use the Bootsrap tab show method
          next.tab('show');
        };
        // Tab Cycle function
        var tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);

        // Tab click event handler
        $('a').on('click', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          // Stop the cycle
          clearInterval(tabCycle);
          // Show the clicked tabs associated tab-pane
          $(this).tab('show');
          // Start the cycle again in a predefined amount of time
          setTimeout(function () {
          //tabCycle = setInterval(tabChange, 5000);
          }, 15000);
      });        
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

**---EDIT:**

To solve that the function is called multiple times you need to unbind the scroll event.

Add this to your code: `$(window).off('scroll');`

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if (checkVisible($('#Block'))) {
            $(window).off('scroll'); # add this
            var tabChange = function () {
```

Comment: It works! But I have a problem now about the switch for the tabs. It's very very fast an it's set to 5000 ms...

Take a look at the [Demo](http://www.bp-design.fr/Codeur)

Comment: Can you put console.log test to your function? Then you can see what the values are for tabs, active,next and tabCycle @bep42

Comment: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery.min.map, line 0)  ?

Comment: I think the problem is within this If statement. The if statement checks if the object is visible by every scroll movement. Therefore the switching does not work. You have to find a way to call the function only 1 time. I might post some code tomorrow. @bep42

Comment: Thanks a lot Rotan, i'll definitely look into it but I'm feeling lost. Hope you'll find a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my answer! now it works ;) Hope it helps you! @bep42

Comment: It works very well mate! Thanks a lot Rotan, you definitely rock !

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Happy coding! @bep42